# Problema al intentar eliminar más de una columna en mi aplicación Python con CustomTkinter

Tags: python, mysql, tcl

Estoy desarrollando un programa en python con CustomTkinter que sirve para crear tablas en una base de datos, tiene varios elementos para configurar cada columna, como su nombre, el tipo de datos, su longitud etc, a lado de cada columna hay un boton para eliminarla, hasta abajo del todo hay 2 botones que son para crear la tabla y añadir más columnas, el problema surge en la función para eliminar columnas, solo puedo eliminar una sola columna, cuando intento eliminar más de una me sale un error en consola.
Aquí el codigo para añadir la columna y eliminarla:

```
#Funcion para añadir columna
            def añadir_columna():
                self.lista_combobox = []

                nueva_fila = self.boton_añadir_columna.grid_info()['row'] + 1

                self.boton_añadir_columna.grid(row=nueva_fila, column=1, pady=10, columnspan=6)

                self.boton_crear_columna.grid(row=nueva_fila, column=0, pady=10, columnspan=4)
                
                self.entrada_nombre_columna = ctk.CTkEntry(marco, placeholder_text="Nombre de la columna")
                self.entrada_nombre_columna.grid(row=nueva_fila - 1,column=0, padx=10,pady=10)
                
                self.opcion_var_type = ctk.StringVar(value="Elija un tipo de dato")
                self.combobox_type = ctk.CTkComboBox(marco,
                                                    values=['VARCHAR', 'INT', 'FLOAT', 'TIMESTAMP', 'BOOLEAN'],
                                                    variable=self.opcion_var_type,
                                                    width=160)
                self.combobox_type.grid(row=nueva_fila - 1,column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
                self.opcion_var_type.trace_add("write", opcion_type)

                #Campo para definir la longitud

                #Funcion para verificar que el valor de el Entry() es numero
                def validar_input(nuevo_valor):
                    return nuevo_valor.isdigit()
                
                self.entrada_length = ctk.CTkEntry(marco,placeholder_text="Longitud", validate="key", validatecommand=(ventana_crear.register(validar_input), "%P"))
                self.entrada_length.grid(row=nueva_fila - 1,column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

                self.opcion_var_key = ctk.StringVar(value="Elija una tipo de clave")

                self.combobox_key = ctk.CTkComboBox(marco,
                                                    values=['Ninguna','PRIMARY KEY', 'FOREIGN KEY', 'UNIQUE KEY'],
                                                    width=170,
                                                    variable=self.opcion_var_key)
                self.combobox_key.grid(row=nueva_fila - 1, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
                self.opcion_var_key.trace_add("write", opcion_combobox)

                self.lista_combobox.append(self.combobox_key)
                
                opcion_var_ai = ctk.BooleanVar()
                opcion_var_ai.set(False)
                
                self.check_box = ctk.CTkCheckBox(marco,
                                                text="Auto Incremento",
                                                variable=opcion_var_ai)
                self.check_box.grid(row=nueva_fila - 1,column=4, padx=10,pady=10)
                
                opcion_var_null = ctk.BooleanVar()
                opcion_var_null.set(False)

                self.check_box_null = ctk.CTkCheckBox(marco,
                                                    text="NOT NULL",
                                                    variable=opcion_var_null)
                self.check_box_null.grid(row=nueva_fila - 1,column=5, padx=10, pady=10)

                def eliminar_columna():
                     self.entrada_nombre_columna.destroy()
                     self.combobox_type.destroy()
                     self.entrada_length.destroy()
                     self.combobox_key.destroy()
                     self.check_box.destroy()
                     self.check_box_null.destroy()
                     self.boton_eliminar_columna.destroy()

                self.boton_eliminar_columna = ctk.CTkButton(marco,
                                                            text="Eliminar columna",
                                                            fg_color="#D2122E",
                                                            hover_color="#7C0A02",
                                                            command=eliminar_columna)
                self.boton_eliminar_columna.grid(row=nueva_fila - 1, column=6, padx=10, pady=10)

            #Creamos el boton para crear la tabla
            self.boton_crear_columna = ctk.CTkButton(marco,
                                        text="Crear tabla")
            self.boton_crear_columna.grid(row=5,column=0,pady=10, columnspan=4)

            #Creamos el boton para añadir una columna
            self.boton_añadir_columna = ctk.CTkButton(marco,
                                                 text="Añadir columna",
                                                 command=añadir_columna)
            self.boton_añadir_columna.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=10, columnspan=6)

            añadir_columna()
```

Aquí el error que sale al intentar eliminar más de una columna:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/coloco/Documentos/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "/home/coloco/Documentos/Cursos/Python/Día 26_36/interfaz/interfaz_grafica.py", line 943, in eliminar_columna
    self.check_box.destroy()
  File "/home/coloco/Documentos/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_checkbox.py", line 169, in destroy
    self._variable.trace_remove("write", self._variable_callback_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 477, in trace_remove
    self._tk.deletecommand(cbname)
_tkinter.TclError: can't delete Tcl command
```

Se que no es la mejor manera para eliminar la columna pero fue lo primero que se me ocurrió.
Por eso pido ayuda para mejorar el codigo, ya sea mejorando el codigo actual de la funcion para eliminar la columna o crear la funcion desde 0

Comment: Hipoteticamente, el código debería de funcionar. Sin embargo, me es imposible ejecutarlo por falta de información. Podrías agregar un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) por favor? Además, no puedo darte consejos sin antes responder a la duda planteada, ya que si no, no sería una respuesta. Aunque, como consejo inicial, considera usar un treeview (o como se lo llame en customtkinter), que está diseñado y optimizado para mostrar un arbol de items (a pesar de eso, te puede servir para crear una tabla en la interfaz grafica).

Answer (score 0):

Ese error es típico de intentar destruir un widget que ya no existe del lado de TCL, por ejemplo llamar dos veces al método `.destroy()` de un mismo widget.

En tu caso es eso exactamente lo que pasa:

- Al crear los widgets de cada fila del grid les asignas una referencia de los mismos a los atributos de instancia `self.entrada_nombre_columna`, `self.check_box`, etc.
- Al añadir otra fila de widgets resignas de nuevo a esos atributos los nuevos widgets, por lo que al final **esos atributos hacen siempre referencia a los  widgets de la ultima fila del grid**, los de la ultima columna agregada a la tabla de tu BD.
- Cuando pulsas un botón "Eliminar columna" (da igual cual)  eliminas los widgets de la ultima fila agregada mediante `.grid()`.
- Al volver a pulsar otro botón "Eliminar columna" intentas destruir de nuevo los widgets de la ultima fila, de ahí el error.

Una forma de solucionarlo es almacenar las referencias de los widgets de cada fila en alguna estructura, como una lista o un diccionario. Cuando quieras eliminar una fila completa de widgets basta con buscar la fila en tu estructura de datos, iterar sobre los widgets de esa fila y llamar a su método `destroy`.

Te dejo un ejemplo basado en tu código con algunos añadidos para que pueda ser reproducido:

```
import customtkinter as ctk


class MainApplication(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.filas = {}
        self.table_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self)
        self.table_frame.pack(anchor=ctk.NW, expand=False, fill=ctk.X)
        self.boton_añadir_columna = ctk.CTkButton(
            self, text="Añadir columna", command=self.añadir_columna
            )
        self.boton_añadir_columna.pack(anchor=ctk.NW, expand=True, fill=ctk.X)

    def añadir_columna(self):
        if not self.filas:
            indice_nueva_fila = 0
        else:
            last_row = next(reversed(self.filas.values()))
            indice_nueva_fila = last_row["widgets"][-1].grid_info()["row"] + 1

        entrada_nombre_columna = ctk.CTkEntry(
            self.table_frame,
            placeholder_text="Nombre de la columna"
            )
        entrada_nombre_columna.grid(
            row=indice_nueva_fila, column=0, padx=10, pady=10
            )

        opcion_var_type = ctk.StringVar(value="Elija un tipo de dato")
        combobox_type = ctk.CTkComboBox(
            self.table_frame,
            values=['VARCHAR', 'INT', 'FLOAT', 'TIMESTAMP', 'BOOLEAN'],
            variable=opcion_var_type,
            width=160
            )
        combobox_type.grid(row=indice_nueva_fila, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        # opcion_var_type.trace_add("write", opcion_type)

        # Campo para definir la longitud

        # Funcion para verificar que el valor de el Entry() es numero
        def validar_input(nuevo_valor):
            return nuevo_valor.isdigit()

        entrada_length = ctk.CTkEntry(
            self.table_frame,
            placeholder_text="Longitud",
            validate="key",
            # validatecommand=(ventana_crear.register(validar_input), "%P")
            )
        entrada_length.grid(row=indice_nueva_fila, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

        opcion_var_key = ctk.StringVar(value="Elija una tipo de clave")

        combobox_key = ctk.CTkComboBox(
            self.table_frame,
            values=['Ninguna', 'PRIMARY KEY', 'FOREIGN KEY', 'UNIQUE KEY'],
            width=170,
            variable=opcion_var_key
            )
        combobox_key.grid(row=indice_nueva_fila, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
        # opcion_var_key.trace_add("write", opcion_combobox)

        opcion_var_ai = ctk.BooleanVar()
        opcion_var_ai.set(False)

        check_box = ctk.CTkCheckBox(
            self.table_frame,
            text="Auto Incremento",
            variable=opcion_var_ai
            )
        check_box.grid(row=indice_nueva_fila, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

        opcion_var_null = ctk.BooleanVar()
        opcion_var_null.set(False)

        check_box_null = ctk.CTkCheckBox(
            self.table_frame,
            text="NOT NULL",
            variable=opcion_var_null
            )
        check_box_null.grid(row=indice_nueva_fila, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)

        def eliminar_columna(button):
            columna = str(button)
            for widget in self.filas[columna]["widgets"]:
                widget.destroy()
            del self.filas[columna]

        boton_eliminar_columna = ctk.CTkButton(
            self.table_frame,
            text=f"Eliminar columna",
            fg_color="#D2122E",
            hover_color="#7C0A02"
            )
        boton_eliminar_columna.configure(
            command=lambda btn=boton_eliminar_columna: eliminar_columna(btn))
        boton_eliminar_columna.grid(
            row=indice_nueva_fila, column=6, padx=10, pady=10
            )

        nueva_fila = {
            "widgets": [
                entrada_nombre_columna,
                combobox_type,
                entrada_length,
                combobox_key,
                check_box,
                check_box_null,
                boton_eliminar_columna
                ],
            "vars": {
                "opcion_var_type": opcion_var_type,
                "opcion_var_key": opcion_var_key,
                "opcion_var_ai": opcion_var_ai,
                "opcion_var_null": opcion_var_null,
                }
            }
        self.filas[str(boton_eliminar_columna)] = nueva_fila


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = ctk.CTk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este ejemplo el diccionario `self.filas` almacena cada fila usando como clave el nombre del botón "Eliminar columna" (por comodidad, para identificarla fácilmente usando una referencia al botón que llama a la *callback*). En la clave *"widgets"* se almacena una lista con los widgets de esa fila del grid y en la clave *"vars"* se almacena un diccionario con las variables usadas para con esos widgets (por si necesitas referencias a ellas en el futuro).

Cuando se pulsa un botón para eliminar una columna de la tabla de tu BD, la callback recibe una referencia del botón que ha provocado su llamada, por lo que basta con buscar el nombre del botón en el diccionario `self.filas` para obtener la lista de widgets a eliminar.

Comment: Ohh entiendo, muchas gracias por la solucion